# Use Ajax File upload in the dotnetnuke custom module

Tags: dotnetnuke

i am running DNN 06.02.X. I design a custom module that needs to upload file to server and i want to use Ajax File Upload control(From AjaxControlToolKit 4.1.60919). for this purpose i Add AjaxControlToolkit.dll to my project reference and must change my project target framework from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4. ok?
my question is: when i debug my module and run dnn (in localhost) get bellow error:

---

### Server Error in '/Mydnn' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

---

Comment: my .ascx code for Ajax upload control ::                       <tr><td><asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" ThrobberID="myThrobber" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><asp:Label ID="myThrobber" runat="server" Style="display: none"><img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Images/Loading.gif") %>"  alt="loading" /></asp:Label></td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your DotNetNuke website to also run on .NET 4.0 by changing the target framework in the Application Pool in IIS

Comment: hi chris,thanks for your reply.I change target framework in the Application Pool in IIS then change my custom module framework,delete web.config file and my module is build successfully. I run the DNN successfully BUT Ajax File Upload control do not work correctly. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem , for more information see Ben's comment at http://support.dotnetnuke.com/issue/ViewIssue.aspx?ID=21667&PROJID=2